# Office UI Fabric JS Dialog Component

Tags: office-addins, outlook-web-addins, office-ui-fabric

I'm currently using Office-UI-Fabric-JS to build a UI for an Outlook Web Add-In.   I will eventually switch over to React.

I've gone over the examples and what I'm not clear about is from where will the HTML for the Dialog box reside?

Calling the Fabric Dialog's "open" API from a TaskPane centers the Dialog within the TaskPane.  I would like it centered on the screen.

However, I'm not sure where the HTML for the dialog should go?

Do I put it in the non-UI Html file  ("FunctionFile.html"), then use div tags?

Do I create an entirely separate HTML page, then load that HTML using Javascript (window.location = "mydialog.html")?

HERE'S A SAMPLE (Where would this HTML go?)

```
    <div class="docs-DialogExample-default">
      <div class="ms-Dialog">
        <div class="ms-Dialog-title">All emails together</div>
          <div class="ms-Dialog-content">
            <p class="ms-Dialog-subText">Your Inbox has changed. No longer does it include favorites, it is a singular destination for your emails.</p>
          <div class="ms-CheckBox">
         <input tabindex="-1" type="checkbox" class="ms-CheckBox-input">
        <label role="checkbox" ...>
          <span class="ms-Label">Option1</span> 
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="ms-CheckBox">
        <input tabindex="-1" type="checkbox" class="ms-CheckBox-input">
        <label role="checkbox" class="ms-CheckBox-field" tabindex="0" aria-       checked="false" name="checkboxa">
          <span class="ms-Label">Option2</span> 
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ms-Dialog-actions">
      <button class="ms-Button ms-Dialog-action ms-Button--primary">
        <span class="ms-Button-label">Save</span> 
      </button>
      <button class="ms-Button ms-Dialog-action">
        <span class="ms-Button-label">Cancel</span> 
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
    <button class="ms-Button docs-DialogExample-button">Open Dialog</button>
    <label class="docs-DialogExample-label"></label>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open a dialog from web addin use the [displayDialogAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.ui?view=office-js#displaydialogasync-startaddress--options--callback-) API provided by Office.js. Some additional documentation can be found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins

Comment: Thanks.  I'm using that API in another area of my code.  I'll just keep using it whenever I need a dialog.   However, what is a typical use of the Office-UI-Fabric-JS Dialog?  Where does the HTML appear?  Is this a deprecated API in favor of React?

Comment: Office-UI-Fabric is for rendering within the web page (and not outlook). In the case of addin, the webpage is the addin pane. So, HTML added by Office-UI-Fabric will appear within the add-in pane.